# Can I have multiple localized listings of the same app?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I am working on an app with both localized English and German content. The content is mainly image assets (maps and such) that contain localized text (place names some of which are nouns like "Sword Valley"). I am using expansion APK's as well. Unfortunately, at the time of writing ,  multiple APK support does not extend to localization.

My question now is, can I publish my app multiple times in the Google Play Store, or does this go against their code of conduct? Will one of my app listings be in danger of getting shut down if I list it multiple times with different package names/localization, or is this accepted.

Comment: So the image assets are in the expansion file? Having text embedded in your images doesn't seem like it would scale very well to the vast variety of Android devices out there.

Comment: @ianhanniballake these are tiled maps, and yes actually it does scale pretty well strangely enough (tested on devices from hdpi up to xxhdpi).